# Setting precision in PHP

Tags: php, precision, scientific-notation, smartsheet-api

I have installed PHP 5.5 on my laptop, who's running Windows.
I'm accessing Smartsheet API, and I supposed to get a column id a number with 18 digits(or sometimes 17). But I get a scientific number:

`1.5441916385627E+15`, not `1544191638562692`

I ran the script, in a Ubuntu server environment, and I see 1544191638562692. The same, a ran in a OS X Maverick environment, and it's the same the integer format.

I was searching for this matter, and seems to be the precision.

If I'm setting in php, the precision 14 for the OS X Maverick environment like this:

```
<?php
ini_set('precision', 14);

    echo (float)$col->id;
    // 1.5441916385627E+15
?>
```

I get also the scientific number.

Can anybody help me with an idea?

Comment: If this is an _id_, you should not treat it as a number, but as a string value.

Comment: If I had to field a guess I'd say that the machines on which you're getting a scientific notation answer are running 32-bit PHP and the Ubuntu machine is running 64-bit. If you're dealing with ID numbers over ~2 billion you should treat them as strings like CBroe suggests for compatibility.

Answer (score 1):

As has been mentioned in the comments, this sounds like an issue with running 32-bit PHP. Smartsheet does provide some [sample PHP code](https://github.com/smartsheet-platform/samples/tree/master/php) to help get you started working with the API. In those samples, the documentation recommends that you treat the ids as strings in 32-bit PHP:

https://github.com/smartsheet-platform/samples/tree/master/php/1-HelloSmartsheet#dependencies

Answer (score 0):

You can output the numbers in the same way on all machines using the formatted string functions in PHP, see https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.sprintf.php for the documentation.

So if you would like the integer as a whole you would use:

```
printf("%u", $number);
```

Comment: @dpuscau note however that the exact number you get out still might be different on different machines. See [this article about floating point math](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html)

Answer (score 0):

One is of possible ways to do it, for example, converting the JSON into an array I had to specify JSON_BIGINT_AS_STRING:

```
$ColumnsArray = json_decode($data, true,515,JSON_BIGINT_AS_STRING);
```